# Assert [assert] == [assertion] == [assertions]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

I think those tags are basically the same. So they should be synonyms, or merged, or something:

- [assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assert): 1,087 questions

  > An assertion is a statement, which aborts a program when it evaluates
  >   to false. Assert is typically used for debugging and situations which
  >   should never happen.
- [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertion): 322 questions

  > An assertion is a software construct where the developer states
  >   ("asserts") a condition that he believes will always be true. If the
  >   condition evaluates to false an exception is generated.
- [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions): 444 questions

  > Assertion is a method of verifying, if the code works as it was
  >   designed to. For instance, after reading an XML file, the result
  >   should contain exactly one root node. Failed assertion means, that
  >   program is in an unstable state and usually in such case its execution
  >   is terminated.

But I don't have enough score in those tags, so I can't suggest them as synonyms.

Note I don't usually use assertions, so maybe I am wrong and there is some difference I don't see. But then tag descriptions should be edited to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm confused about the "I don't have enough score" bit. You can create tag synonyms at 2500 rep.

Comment: @TomFenech I get "Creating a tag synonym requires 5 score in this tag".

Comment: Although, it is the least used one, I think [assertion] should be the main tag.

Comment: @PierreArlaud: That's more of a regex question than a Python question, but anyway, it checks whether `test_string` consists of 3 digits, a hyphen, and 4 more digits. Sounds like an attempt to determine whether `test_string` is a phone number.

Comment: @PierreArlaud How is your question related to this thread?

Comment: @Oriol Perhaps Pierre was (for reasons unknown) suggesting that Python is not in fact the same as English.

Comment: @JLRishe Thanks for your support (for reasons unknown). English, like any human language (no, Lojban doesn't count) is too ambiguous to be used in computer theory. Doesn't make Python a bad language though :-)

Comment: Where did these definitions come from?

Comment: @topdizel Those are the tag excerpts.

Comment: The expression in the title would not compile because you can't compare the types bool and tag.

Comment: @usr Only in some languages. In others, it just returns false. (In fact, it's probably an error because of the brackets, not because of the comparisons)

Comment: It has been over a year since the last comment and all three tags still exist. Unless I missed something, it looks like the conciseness is to merge (at least two of them, and improve the name of the other if kept separate). Is there a reason why nothing has happened?

Answer (score 9):

There are two concepts here.  On one hand there are "assert commands" (or "assert statements" if you prefer) such as are found in Euclid, Java, and Eiffel. These are commands in an imperative language. Closely related is C's "assert macro" and "assert" subroutines found in lots of libraries. These assert commands, macros, and subroutines are used for run-time checking.

On the other hand there are "assertions" which are used in design and analysis techniques pioneered by Floyd and Hoare, with some earlier work by Turing and Naur.  Assertions in this sense are used either to guide the design or to analyze a design to see whether it is correct or not (i.e. for verification).  The use of assertions in this sense does not imply any run-time checking, though it doesn't preclude it either.

From the tag descriptions, it seems that `assert` and `assertion` are being used in the first sense while `assertions` is used in the second sense.

Comment: That said, almost all recent traffic on `assertions` is about "assert commands" and the like.

Comment: I don't like that kind of subtle distinction.  If we're going to have a tag for "design assertions", we should retag them e.g. `design-assertions` and synonym/merge the three tags OP mentioned.

Comment: Currently `assertions` is a synonym for `assertion` but `assert` and `assertion` somehow still remain distinct.

Answer (score 3):

I also think they must be made synonyms. Currently [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertions) has been made synonymous to [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertion) so it couldn't be used for Floyd and Hoare's design technique. [assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assert) should now also be made a synonym of [assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assertion)

Some new tags must be created for Floyd–Hoare logic's assertions with a proper name and wiki

Comment: If you know of questions which need a tag regarding the Floyd-Hoare thing, you have more than sufficient rep to create a tag... I would suggest [hoare-logic] as that seems to be what [Wikipedia landed on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoare_logic) but I know nothing about the subject.